# Do I need to update the watch when new sub-folder add in the monitor folder

Tags: python, pyinotify

I have watch a folder that will create a new sub-folder use date as name(e.g 201105124) everyday. I have start a daemon to watch it but if a new sub-folder added, the event in the new sub-folder cannot be trigger. IS that I need to update the watch for the new folder?

Thx for your answer.

Regards
Roy

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you need to use `update_watch` after directory creation.

Comment: `add_watch(auto_add=True)` is an easier solution. Hence the other answer is better.

Answer (score 2):

And I find that there is an parameter auto_add in function add_watch,
which can auto add the directory in the watch when it is created.
But it need the event IN_CREATE.